# Visual Studio restarting on adding data source to report

Tags: c#, reportviewer, report-viewer2010

My visual studio is restarting when I try to add a data source to my report.rdlc file.
I'm using VS 2010 and reportviewer control and Entity data model as model of database connection.

Comment: have you tried running Visual Studio without addins (in safe-mode)? Start => Run => "devenv /safemode" => ok

Comment: Yeah, I tried but it does not make any changes!

Comment: Visual studio isn't bug proof, I've got a little process for this kind of thing if you can think of an alternative procedure to setup your project give it a try (try any order of actions you can think of). Next up check MS Connect (e.g. this looks very similar to your issue https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/695864/unable-to-add-or-edit-datasources-datasets-for-report-designer-rdlc) to see if it's a known bug and has workarounds, finally if nothing else works.. reinstall time!

Answer (score 0):

Try visual studio diagnostic tool
[Visual Studio Diagnostic Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e8649e35-26b1-4e73-b427-c2886a0705f4/)